# Recursive : shift char with max ASCII value to 1st index, shift remaining charsequence one further;

Tags: string, recursion

the output should be for example shiftMaxChar("acbxdyfjzdmk") ---> ("zacbxdyfjdmk")

At the moment I'm just checking for 'Z' and 'z'.
I am out of ideas, how to realise my problem.

Any tips, where I'm missing my point very much appreciated.

```
 private static String shiftMaxChar(String s){
       assert s != null;
   String sub = "";


    if(s.isEmpty()) return s;


    for (int i = 0; i < s.length() ; i++) {
      if(s.charAt(i) == 90 || s.charAt(i) == 122) {
          char max = s.charAt(i);
          sub = shiftMaxChar(s.substring(0) + max + s.substring(1, s.length() - 1));
      }
    }

return  sub;

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(shiftMaxChar("\"acbxdyf jzdmk\"" ));
    System.out.println(shiftMaxChar("\"\""));
```

Comment: i came to following solution:

Answer (score 1):

We can accomplish this by assuming the previous call has already done this for the rest of the string.

JavaScript code:

```js
function f(s){
  if (s.length < 2)
    return s;

  let rest = f(s.substr(1));
  
  if (s[0] < rest[0])
    return rest[0] + s[0] + rest.substr(1);
    
  return s;
}

console.log(f("acbxdyfjzdmk"));
```

Answer (score 0):

i came to following solution:

```
private static String shiftMaxChar(String s) {
    assert s != null;

    if (s.isEmpty()) {return s;}


    char ascii = s.charAt(0);
    char asciiEnd = s.charAt(s.length() - 1);
    if (ascii < asciiEnd) {
        String sub = shiftMaxChar(s.substring(1));
        return sub.charAt(0) + ( ascii + sub.substring(1, s.length() - 1));

    } else{
        return shiftMaxChar(s.substring(0, s.length() - 1)) + asciiEnd;
    }
}
```